# UWP app (C#) - Same code click event button

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I have an UWP app published in Microsoft/Windows Store, and I have many repeated code, and I want simplify my code. I have a button that appears several times in my application (always with the same name) and its design changes, but the code is always the same (click event button). To avoid duplicate code, can I write the event code to click the button once and use wherever I want?

Comment: How do you think we should answer the question without code?

Comment: Sure, you put your code in some sort of service class and call it. Am I misunderstanding the question?

Answer (score 1):

It's really easy to do. Create a shared method with the code and in the handler for each Button, just call it from each button's event handler.

Example:

You have a Page with 3 Buttons

```
<Page
    x:Class="App2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button x:Name="Button1" Click="Button1_OnClick"></Button>
        <Button x:Name="Button2" Click="Button2_OnClick"></Button>
        <Button x:Name="Button3" Click="Button3_OnClick"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

And in the code-behind file (MainPage.xaml.cs)

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonHandlers.Handle(sender, e);
    }

    private void Button2_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonHandlers.Handle(sender, e);
    }

    private void Button3_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonHandlers.Handle(sender, e);
    }
}

internal static class ButtonHandlers
{
    public static void Handle(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        // This is shared!
    }
}
```

I think you can get the idea. Anyways, you should take a look to the MVVM architectural pattern. Adding event handlers to Buttons isn't the way to work under XAML based applications, like UWP or WPF :)

Comment: In this case all the buttons make the same?

Comment: They do the same, of course. The logic is inside the Handle method, instead of having a copy the code inside the handler of each button. The goal is to reduce duplication while making the code easy to read and understand :)